# Parse transfermarket link

Tags: php, parsing

how to get ID(the numbers at the end) from links transfermarket site in PHP?
for example http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/claudio-bravo/profil/spieler/40423

```
$url = 'http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/andriy-pyatov/profil/spieler/40423';
$r = parse_url($url);
$endofurl = substr($r['path'], strrpos($r['path'], '/'));
```

$endofurl returns /40423

how to get rid of / ?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution A

Assuming

```
$url = "http://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/andriy-pyatov/profil/spieler/40423";
```

you could use `explode` to split the url and then `end` to get the last element (40423 in this example):

```
$id = explode("/", $url);
$id = end($id);
```

---

### Solution B

In case you really want to use `$endofurl`:

```
$id = substr($endofurl, 1);
```